# Hexadecimal command line file viewer

Tags: c, console

I have been working on a project for several days. It is a command line program for viewing files in hexadecimal. It is usually very fast, but is there any way I could make it more efficient?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc == 2){
        FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if(in == NULL){
            printf("Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
        }else{
            int i = 0, j, br, ln[8];
            char l[16];
            while((br = fread(&l, 1, 16, in)) > 0){
                printf("%08x ", i);
                i += br;
                for(j = 0; j < br; j++){
                    if(l[j] > 0){
                        printf("%02x ", l[j]);
                    }else{
                        printf("?? ");
                    }
                }
                for(j = 0; j < 16 - br; j++){
                    printf("   ");
                }
                for(j = 0; j < br; j++){
                    if(l[j] > 31 && l[j] < 127){
                        printf("%c", l[j]);
                    }else{
                        printf(".");
                    }
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            fclose(in);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Please use the syntax 'hex [file]'\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about: `od -t x1 <file>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a program fails for some reason then it should

- Write a diagnostic message to *standard error* (not standard output),
  so that it can not be mistaken for normal output, e.g. when
  the program runs in a pipe. `strerror(errno)` gives you an error
  message string corresponding to the last error, e.g.
  "No such file or directory" or "Permission denied".
- Terminate with a non-zero status code. You can use predefined
  exit codes from `<sysexits.h>` if that is available on your system,
  or make up your own.

Combining this with the "Avoiding deep nesting" advice from
[Caridorc's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115662/35991), the overall structure would be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: hex [file]\n");
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }

    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot not open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(EX_NOINPUT);
    }

    // ... print hex dump ...

    fclose(in);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // EXIT_SUCCESS == 0
}
```

Your variable names are too short and non-descriptive.

- `i` is the current offset into the file. The correct type for
  a file offset is `off_t`.
- `br` is the amount of bytes read. The correct type would
  be `size_t` (which is what `fread()` returns, so this avoids
  a warning when compiling on a 64-bit architecture).
- `l` is a line buffer.

`j` is OK as a iteration variable, but the scope should be limited to the
for-loop.

The main loop would then start like this:

```
off_t offset = 0;
size_t bytesRead;
char line[16];

while ((bytesRead = fread(&line, 1, 16, in)) > 0){
    printf("%08llx ", offset);
    offset += bytesRead;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < bytesRead; j++){
        printf("%02x ", line[j]);
    }
```

I don't know why you want to print a NUL-byte as `??`, therefore
I have removed that part.

The padding can be done by printing an empty string
with a field width:

```
    printf("%*.s", 3*(16 - (int)bytesRead), "");
```

The remaining part of the main loop is OK, only that I would
generally use more space, at least around parentheses and keywords:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < bytesRead; j++) {
        if (line[j] > 31 && line[j] < 127) {
            printf("%c", line[j]);
        } else {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Compiler diagnostic**

My first suggestion is very easy to follow, just compile your code with:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic
```

This will give you all sorts of nice warnings for possible errors, your code only raises one, kudos!

> ```
> hex.c: In function ‘main’:
> hex.c:10:31: warning: unused variable ‘ln’ [-Wunused-variable]
>          int i = 0, j, br, ln[8];
> ```

Just remove `, ln[8]` from your code to simplify and silence the warning.

**Avoiding deep nesting**

Your code now looks like:

```
if proper_condition1() {
    if proper_condition2() {
        // do_stuff()
    } else ()
} else()
```

It is deeply nested. But beware that deep nesting increases complexity  and I cannot clearly see how trouble-some situations are handled, I suggest the pattern:

```
if NOT proper_condition1() {
    handle_error()
}
if NOT proper_condition2() {
    handle_error()
}
// do_stuff()
```

After flattening the error conditions, your code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2) {
            printf("Please use the syntax 'hex [file]'\n");
            return 1;
        }

    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(in == NULL){
      printf("Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
      return 2;
    }

    int i = 0, j, br;
    char l[16];
    while((br = fread(&l, 1, 16, in)) > 0){
            printf("%08x ", i);
            i += br;
            for(j = 0; j < br; j++){
                    if(l[j] > 0){
                            printf("%02x ", l[j]);
                    }else{
                            printf("?? ");
                    }
            }
            for(j = 0; j < 16 - br; j++){
                    printf("   ");
            }
            for(j = 0; j < br; j++){
                    if(l[j] > 31 && l[j] < 127){
                            printf("%c", l[j]);
                    }else{
                            printf(".");
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

That I like not only for putting in evidence the strategy to deal with errors and for being less nested, but also because it gives different return values for different outcomes:

- `1` if the call syntax was invalid
- `2` if the file is not readable
- `0` is everything goes fine

This way a script can easily check if things went right or wrong and more importantly *in which way it failed* that may be useful for further processing.

**Built-in usage**

Even if C is mid-level, and thus has much less built-ins than say Python or Ruby, there are still some to take advantage of, an example relevant to this code is the [**`isprint`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isprint.htm) function, that may be used in place of `l[j] > 31 && l[j] < 127` to improve readability.

**Avoid overkill usage of `printf`**

`printf` is a very powerful function, and I like avoiding using powerful functions when smaller and less powerful options are available:

**Ternary simplification**

Till the end of your code, after making my modifications, you always use `putchar` just the argument changes, this makes a great opportunity to simplify with a ternary:

```
for(j = 0; j < br; j++){
    putchar(isprint(l[j]) ? l[j] : '.');
}
```

This is much shorter then `if` and `else` and also more readable as the ternary is less powerful in that it only allows expressions (`if` also allows statements). I also like that we got rid of the duplication of `putchar`.

- `printf("?? ")` becomes `fputs("?? ", stdout)`
- `printf(".")` becomes `putchar('.')`
- `printf("\n")` becomes `putchar('\n')`
- `printf("%c", l[j])` becomes `putchar(l[j])`

**Small helper function**

Given the loop:

```
            for(j = 0; j < 16 - br; j++){
                printf("   ");
            }
```

It is not so obvious at first glance how many spaces it prints, I defined a small helper function:

```
void print_spaces(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        putchar(' ');
    }
}
```

So that calling it makes the matter much more obvious:

```
print_spaces(4 * (16 - bytes_read) );
```

I always think that too many functions is a much better problem than too little functions, so I err on the side of writing many, even tiny, helpers.

Comment: @Daniel Gee please un-accept this answer, we are different from SO in that a good answer may take a day or more to arrive. After a day or two you may accept an answer.

Comment: I do hope that you don't mind some overlap between our answers. I had prepared those arguments already while you posted and amended your answer.

Comment: @MartinR Surely not, on a given piece of code there is only so much to say and I am sure you came up with your ideas by yourself, so no problem. Your answer also contains many sensible improvments not found in mine, so you have my upvote.

Comment: @Caridorc should I post my updated code under the question?

Comment: @DanielGee: No, you should not edit the question after receiving an answer. Have a look at http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c for the possible options (such as a follow-up question).

Comment: Concerning `putc() fputs()` vs. `printf(string_literal)`:  Many an optimizing compiler will create the same code, so I favor the function that best conveys the code's intent. If code had lots of needed `printf()`calls, would likely stick with that even for `printf("\n");`, else `puts("")` works fine.

Comment: @chux I also said for simplicity, printf for a single char may be optimized away but is also weird too read as the reader may wonder why printf was chosen when putchar may suffice, anyhow this is not a fundamental point.